# CSS not diplayed correctly in html view extension

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

Newby here! Can anyone please explain why my CSS is not displaying correctly in the HTML viewer? It looks perfect on the live server. I'm unable to locate the answer inline.

I'm using HTML Preview by Thomas Haakon Townsend.

Kevin
[screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hennt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the path you've provided to the CSS file in the HTML document.

Your current path is:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Given that your `index.html` is inside the `Lesson 1` folder and your CSS file is directly inside the `css` folder (and not inside the `Lesson 1` folder), you'll need to move one directory up to access the CSS. You can do this using `..` to move one directory level up.

Change the path in your `index.html` to:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
```

This adjustment tells the browser to go one directory up from `Lesson 1` and then access the `css` folder to find the `style.css` file.